# Attachment size when sending email through php from an IIS 7 server

Tags: php, email, iis, size, attachment

Hello I am struggling to find an answer the last couple days and I ve searched a lot but without success

I set up a webserver using IIS 7 and its running fine I ve got php mysql and I can run web applications like Epesi . I can also upload to my server using php without problems any size declared in php.ini. I have a mail web application called Roundcube (I ve tried others also) I can send and receive emails and attachments but in limited size. I ve narrowed it down to 2mb anything below 2 mb I can send and download

The errors I get from the internet explorer console within the server is

1) on creation of a new email
HTML1115: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=7') ignored because document mode is already finalized. 
?_task=mail&_id=1953546440546bbabb2d79a&_action=compose

2) while waiting to send a 4mb attachment (after a minute)
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Php\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exceeded configured activity timeout
IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.

IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.

IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.

The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.

The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed

Ive also tried to add to web.config

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
            <requestLimits>
            maxAllowedContentLength=33600000 
            maxReceivedMessageSize=33600000
            maxRequestLength="4000"
            executionTimeout="45"
            </requestLimits>

        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
```

but with no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after a lot of trial and error I ve found the solution to my problem I had to increase the ActivityTimeout parameter and RequestTimeout on IIS MAnager->FastCGI Settings->(edit php application) to 90 and 270 hope this helps somebody!